# twitter posting from webpage button (in onestep)

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I implemented twitter posting button on my web site using [twitter codeigniter library](http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/).)
using that button, I can posting my writing to twitter. (like social sharing button)
It works well.

To posting a writing,
there are two steps like below.

**1. getting user allow/disallow page**

[image]

**2. message and posting page**
[image]

but, some kinds of social sharing button skip the first step.
they let the user post his writings just 1 page step.
(write message and push post button, that's all)

So, my question is how can I skip the first step so that 
users just write message push posting button in one page step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Twitter's "Tweet" button:

http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

If you're logged in you don't need to authorize an app before tweeting

Comment: thanks alex. Can I set some default text on that text area? for example writing's url?

Comment: Ah, I found it~. Thanks any way.  http://www.technostarry.com/extras/add-a-custom-twitter-status-message-to-a-link-or-a-button/

Answer (score 1):

https://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

That is a button that allows users to share pages without having to "Approve" your website.